# Opt-out of "Application was sent" emails from Jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, email

Right now it's impossible to opt-out from email "Success! Your application was sent" (this email from "Developers Jobs" section on SO when applying vacancy).

Is it possible to have such opportunity and don't receive this email?

PS: Can't understand what wrong with this (so many downvotes)!?  I don't need this email, I want to save SO server performance/capacity, SO don't have to waste time, CPU, memory, jobs, workers, etc, maybe don't use 3d party service for sending this email which I'm not interested in...

Comment: Do you usually have the ability to opt out of confirmation emails when you sign up for something?

Comment: @Andy But it isn't signup, It's definitely different email.

Comment: I've updated my question and clarify that this email from "Developers Jobs" and is known to be sent when applying job vacancy.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot opt out of this email as this is considered a transactional email, confirming your application was sent to the employer.

Comment: I know that I can't  But I would like to be able...

Comment: Moreover, I know that I've applied vacancy))) I trust SO, I believe that when I apply vacancy - SO will deliver my CV, so it's just a spam...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak `I know that I can't  But I would like to be able` What are you suggesting here? That they build the feature for you?...

Comment: @Vladimir Kovpak: You may trust SO, but SO can't trust that you were the one who sent in that application. What if someone hijacked your account and used it to apply for jobs you didn't want to without your knowledge? Then you'd start receiving messages out of the blue from employers thinking you were interested in them. Which do you think is spammier, those unsolicited emails or the confirmation email?